# Wordpress - WP-Polls - How to display number of people who voted for the poll?

Tags: wordpress, counting

Is there any solution to display number of people who voted for the specific poll? I want to display value somewhere in Wordpress theme file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite literally in the [Plugin Page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-polls/). Here's the example they use:

```
<?php if ( function_exists( 'get_pollvoters' ) ): ?>
    <?php get_pollvoters(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Ohhh sorry for the question, I didn't notice it. Thank you!